# How insert xmlhttp.responseText into an already existing dropdown html element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Goal:** I want to retrieve values from the getFaculties() on the Connection.php snippet and insert them into `<select>` on my form

Piece of code of my form

```html
<form id="myform" method="GET">
  <label>Varsity Name</label><br>
  <select name="selVarsityName" id="selVarsityName" onchange="dropUpdate();">
  <?php
    require 'Connection.php';
    $conn->getVarsities();
  ?>                
  </select><br>

  <label>Faculty Name</label>
  <select name="selFaculty" id="selFaculty">
  </select><br>
```

This is the function that does the request...

```js
function dropUpdate() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('selFaculty').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  var ghgh = document.getElementById('selVarsityName').value;
  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'Middle.php?selVarsityName=' + ghgh, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

This is the code on the Middle.php page.

```js
require './Connection.php';

if (isset($_GET['selVarsityName'])) {
  $selVarsityName = $_GET['selVarsityName'];
  $conn->getFaculties($selVarsityName);
}
```

Code on my Connection.php page

```js
function getVarsities() {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_university`";

  $result = mysqli_query($this - > link, $query);

  if ($result) {


    echo "<option>Select University</option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $VarsityName = $row['university_name'];

      echo "<option>$VarsityName</option>";
    }

  } else {
    echo "record not found";
  }
}

function getFaculties($ff) {
  $uni_id = 0;
  $query = "SELECT `university_id` FROM `tb_university` WHERE `university_name` = '$ff'";
  $result = mysqli_query($this - > link, $query);
  if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $uni_id = $row['university_id'];
    }


  }
  $query1 = "SELECT `faculty_name` FROM `faculty` WHERE `university_id` = $uni_id";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($this - > link, $query1);
  if ($result1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $fal_name = $row['faculty_name'];
      echo < option > $fal_name < /option>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to set `$conn` in `Middle.php`.

Comment: Please remove the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->` when you use the `<>` snippet editor to tidy code

Comment: @Barmar...Look i can retrieve all the data that i want to the form, the issue is i do not how to put that data into a <select>...I can put the data in a  <div> and it shows, all i need  to know is how to put it into a <selelct>..